# to fit these shoes / to try on these shoes

Tags: phrase-meaning

1. As I understand it, the sentences have the same meaning, haven't they?
2. "To fit the shoes" is more common than "to try on the shoes", but "to try on these shoes" is more common than "to fit these shoes", as you can see [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20fit%20the%20shoes%2Cto%20try%20on%20the%20shoes%2C%20to%20fit%20these%20shoes%2Cto%20try%20on%20these%20shoes&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=50&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20fit%20the%20shoes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20try%20on%20the%20shoes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20fit%20these%20shoes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20try%20on%20these%20shoes%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cto%20fit%20the%20shoes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20try%20on%20the%20shoes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20fit%20these%20shoes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20try%20on%20these%20shoes%3B%2Cc0). Does it have any logic?

> I want **to fit** these shoes.
>
> I want **to try on** these shoes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Try on**" is a one-time test to see if something fits. This is an idiomatic way of saying you want to try clothes or shoes in a store.

"**I want to fit**" is more long-term - it means you want to fit into something, potentially more than once. Although a trying-on of clothes in a store is sometimes called "a fitting", "I want to fit" isn't really an idiomatic way of saying you want to try something on.

You should note that "I want to fit" could sound like you can change something about yourself. For example, a person hoping to lose weight might say "I want to fit (into) these clothes", meaning they don't fit them now, but they hope to.

You can also reverse the statement, so rather than say "I want to fit the dress", you could say "I want the *dress* to fit *me*". This way around, it could imply that the item of clothing could change - perhaps be altered, or 'let out' so that it fits you.

Answer (score 3):

I think your question is based on some misconceptions.

Firstly, [**fit** has several definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fit).  One of them, probably the most common, is

> to conform correctly to the size or shape of

Using this sense, we say **the shoes fit me**.

Other definitions include

> to insert or adjust until correctly in place

or

> to make or adjust to the right shape and size

We use this sense like **The farrier fitted the shoes to the horse's hoofs**.

So saying "I want to fit these shoes" sounds like "I wish my feet were appropriately sized for these shoes", not "I am going to put on these shoes", but another interpretation is "I am going to install these shoes."  ([Shoe](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shoe) also has multiple meanings.)

Also, "to try on" means to test something to see if it fits, but "to fit" (in the sense of "to install") is more permanent, and does not mean "to test".

---

I wouldn't worry too much about the Ngrams results.  You have to interpret the results in context.  When I look at some of the results, what I find is a lot of things like

> [Now, what would you think if people said to you, “You really need to adjust your feet to fit the shoes.” Wouldn't it be more reasonable to just adjust — or change - the shoes?](https://books.google.com/books?id=zNXpDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT111&dq=%22to%20fit%20the%20shoes%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7-5T1gL3yAhUCFFkFHY6SANkQ6AEwAHoECAcQAg)

The whole point of that is that saying "your feet fit the shoes" is absurd, and the shoes should fit your feet!

Also, because both *fit* and *shoes* have multiple meanings, there are a lot of sentences where *to fit the shoes* can mean something like "to measure someone for shoes" or "to install a metal plate for a brake drum".

Comment: Adjusting feet to fit shoes didn't turn out well for the ugly sisters.